# Eclipse C++: How do you quickly switch between header and implementation files?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-cdt

How do you switch between header (.h) and implementation files (.cpp) in Eclipse when using the C++/CDT environment with a keyboard shortcut?

In XCode you can quickly switch between headers and implementation with applekey option and up/down arrow keys. I was hoping that eclipse had something similar, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

See in menu Window --> Preferences --> "General" category (far left) --> Keys --> "Toggle Source/Header"

Comment: Is there a way to switch between the console and the code editor with a keyboard shortcut? I can't find it here...

Comment: This is incorrect. CDT overrides ctrl+tab with a "Toggle Source Header" function.

Comment: legendary. thank you

Answer (score 7):

Ctrl + Tab is the default shortcut and [here](http://bristle.com/Tips/Eclipse.htm) is a list of some of the more useful shortcut keys in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is the default shortcut. You can change it in Window->Preferences->General->Keys - Toggle Source/Header

Answer (score 1):

**`F3` to jump between declarations and definitions of specific methods**

This is another good one to know in this context:

- double click on the method name with the mouse, selecting it
- hit F3 (shortcut for Right Click > Open Declaration)

This takes you from the declaration (.hpp) to definition (.cpp) and vice versa depending on which one you are currently in, which is useful if you want to go to the other file to see a specific method when the file is large.

Tested in Eclipse CDT 2019-09.

Answer (score 0):

You can also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click on an identifier ( method name of member,... ). That way you seldomly need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: But while coding, we dont use mouse. So sorry for click.